# Загрузить текстовый файл (русские буквы), который находится на карте памяти в строку

Tags: android, кодировка, java

Проблема вот в чем. При загрузке файла английские буквы нормально отображаются, а вместо русских одни иероглифы. Прошу помочь, уже не знаю что и делать. Заранее благодарен!

Вот код метода:

```
private String openAndRead(String url) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     String str = "";
     String b ="";
     File sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        // добавляем свой каталог к пути
        sdPath = new File(sdPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/WebPage/search/" );
        // формируем объект File, который содержит путь к файлу
        File sdFile = new File(sdPath, "search.encr");
        try {
          // открываем поток для чтения
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sdFile));
          // читаем содержимое
          while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {

              b = b+str;
          }
        Log.d(TAG,"ok");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return b;

}
```

Comment: на эмуляторе?

Answer (score 1):

Родной кодировкой для Android является UTF-8, то есть русский текст будет правильно отображаться только если у него кодировка UTF-8. В случае, если исходных текст имеет другую кодировку, то при чтении его нужно конвертировать из исходной кодировки в UTF-8. Как это сделать - написано в постах [@Dex](/users/878/dex) или [@alexis76](/users/18394/alexis76)

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow:

> FileReader always uses the platform default encoding which is generally a bad idea. Instead you'll have to use new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(...), <encoding>)

Вдруг вам понравился BufferedReader:

```
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(new    
    FileInputStream (textFile), encoding );
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader (inputStreamReader);
```

Answer (score 0):

Засадный момент в том, что дефолтная кодировка для текста ISO-8859-1,
Поэтому требуется перекодирование. 
Например так (здесь текстовый файл в кодировке CP1251):

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(fn,"rw");
while ((line = file.readLine()) != null){
      line = new String(line.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "CP1251");
```